# =URL() Script code issue | ReferenceError: btn is not defined (line 9, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having an issue trying to use a script to extract the URL from one test with hyperlink.

Here is the script I am using:

```
function URL(reference) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var args = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i);
  try {
    var range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(args[1] + 'is not a valid range');
  }
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < formulas[0].length; j++) {
      var url = formulas[i][j].match(/=hyperlink\("([^"]+)"/i);
      row.push(url ? url[1] : '');
    }
    output.push(row);
  }
  return output
}
```

After I run the script I get this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null (line 9, file "Code")

Any idea where the issue comes from and I can solve this?

Comment: Does  line 9 contain the `var range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);`? The method `getRange()` expect either a [a1 notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) or a [row, column notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column). Does `args[1]` correpond to any of those?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to look at this and modified my code using a1 notation in line 9 but still does not work. Would you be so kind as to take a look maybe ? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ofTittp2Al-olFJ2kYWU8FaoEXBoPchnUmco3Te30QA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see you issue now - it looks like you are trying to use a custom function? Unfortunately this is not possible, because if you type into a cell e.g.  `=URL(A3)`, the reference will only contain the display value of `A`  - not the URL! And  `getActiveRange()` will return you the currently selected cell (so the one into which you paste `=URL(A3)` - not `A3` itself. Do you want to attach the script instead to a button so that it works on the curerntly selected cell when you press the button?

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. Thank you. That would be great to find a workaround indeed.

Do you want to attach the script instead to a button so that it works on the curerntly selected cell when you press the button? --> Yes sounds good to me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Retrieve the hyperlink with the [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) and assign the script to a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)

- The way you are following so far (extracting a hyperlink from a formula) is an old solution that does not work anymore
- Currently, to retrieve a spreadsheet you need to use the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) method [spreadsheets:get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- To use the Sheest API in Apps Script, you need to [enable it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) in the editor
- Sample script:

```
function URL() {
  var spreadsheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var id = spreadsheet.getId();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var linkArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(id, {ranges: sheet.getName() + "!" + range.getA1Notation(), fields: "sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink"});
  var link = linkArray.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[0].values[0].hyperlink;
  var cellInB = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2);
  cellInB.setValue(link);
}
```

- As mentioned in the comments, in your use case it is not possible to use custom formulas, instead create a drawing and assign the script to it:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

- Now, select a cell in column A, click on the button and the link will be populated in column B.

UPDATE:

To retrieve all URLs at once you can use the followign script and run it manually:

```
function getAllURLs() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var id = spreadsheet.getId();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange("A2").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1, 1);
  var linkArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(id, {ranges: sheet.getName() + "!" + range.getA1Notation(), fields: "sheets/data/rowData/values/hyperlink"});
  var links = [];
  for (var i = 0; i< linkArray.sheets[0].data[0].rowData.length; i++){
  var link = linkArray.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[i].values[0].hyperlink;
    links[i] = [];
    links[i].push(link);
  }
  var cellsInB = sheet.getRange(2,2,lastRow-1, 1);
  cellsInB.setValues(links);
}
```

Comment: That's awesome it works indeed now ! The problem I have is that I have to click on the button for EACH of the cells I want to exatract the URL from. The initial idea using a script or formula was to automate it (just scrolling down the formula and extracts automatically all URLs of cells on the left) as I will have more than 1000 cells to repeat the action ... Is it possible to deal with this ?

Comment: It's possible to run the script manually (or on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers))and implement that it shall perform the request for all cells in column A.  Would that be a good solution for you?

Comment: That would definitely be a solution for me if this can perform the script for all cells in column A instantly !

Comment: Working !!! You're the best thanks a mill @ziganotschka

Comment: Done ! With pleasure :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have `try/catch` block that throws error, but in `catch` block you are trying to iterate `null` object again:

```
try {
    var range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);
}
catch(e) {
  throw new Error(args[1] + 'is not a valid range'); // <- `args[1]` is producing new error
}
```

If you change `catch` content to `throw new Error(formula + 'is not a valid range');`, it should work.